# How to attach to IIS process (w3wp.exe) on Windows 10/IIS 10?

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

Using Visual Studio 2013 in Windows 8.1, I've been used to debug applications hosted in IIS by attaching to the w3wp.exe process running the Application Pool.

After upgrading from 8.1 to 10, I can no longer see any w3wp.exe processes in the Attach to Process dialog even if the Show processes from all users checkbox is checked.

What is the process name for application pools in IIS 10? Maybe there's another way to debug IIS applications in Windows 10?

**UPDATE:**
The issue was that all w3wp.exe processes had stopped. Simply hitting the URL by a browser again started the w3wp.exe process, and I was able to debug as usual.

Comment: See my own answer. For some reason all w3wp.exe processes had stopped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For some reason all w3wp.exe processes had stopped. I just recycled the app pool and refreshed the browser window and w3wp.exe started and showed up in the Attach to Process dialog as normal.

I don't know for sure if this is an IIS 10 related issue, but I never experienced this in earlier versions of IIS.

Comment: I have isolated the issue - you need to have recent requests sent to the site. As you said - refresh the browser. That fixed it for me

Answer (score 29):

Open Visual Studio in Administrator Mode, then Debug -> attach to process -> tick the check box "Show processes from all user", select w3wp.exe. Administration mode is required for debugging the source code.

Comment: Isn't there a setup process that you have to attach the url to?

Answer (score 16):

I am using the windows 10 debugger to attatch to w3wp.exe just fine, are you sure you are ticking the `show processes from all users` tickbox in the bottom left? iis is ran against its own user.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue today. To resolve the issue, I had to change the application pool to run as 32 bit application since I am debugging in visual studio 2017, which is still a 32 bit application.

[image]