# Dynamics 365 - How to Debug the code from it’s beginning

Tags: debugging, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I’m working with Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations, Enterprise Edition.

In Visual Studio, is there any way to Debug the code from it's beginning?

For example: When I Login into Dynamics main page, I want to see Line by Line what’s going on.

Comment: client side or server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The D365FO is application hosted on IIS. Therefore,
2. You need to attach to IIS process to debug a business logic. The executable file for IIS process has name w3wp.exe. See [How to attach to IIS process (w3wp.exe) on Windows 10/IIS 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072195)
3. There are some notes about 'Login into Dynamics main page'. The D365FO has a kernel logic and a business logic. A kernel logic is kind of a framework that calls a business logic. Normally you can debug a business logic and you cannot debug a kernel logic. There are some tricks to debug all code. I don't think It good way for begginers.

Normally you need to:

- set a breakpoint in your business code,
- attach your Visual Studio to IIS process w3wp.exe (a browser opened),
- navigate in the browser to your form/periodic process/report,
- debug you code from the breakpoint.

Comment: Just a note that later platform updates you may need to attach to IISExpress.exe for debugging instead of w3wp.exe due to a change in development architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Microsoft Dynamics 365 Unified Operations: Trace Parser.

Open Trace -> Capture Events-> select all providers-> start. Then open up D365 client Browser, make some selections such as going to General Ledger, then click Stop and import in the tracer.

After selecting the right grouping, below is what I see:

[image]