# IIS Worker Processes list is empty

Tags: wcf, iis, attach-to-process

I try to attach to process in Visual Studio for debugging. The process is WCF-service on IIS. I've read articles about how to get process ID from IIS. They advice to check IIS->Root->Worker Processes and select needed processID, but my list of processes in IIS is empty. The list of available processes ("Attach to Process" window in VS) have not included "w3wp.exe" processes, which represent IIS processes. How can I connect for debugging to hosted WCF?

Visual Studio 2017 professional; IIS v10; Windows 10

**Edited** I've found the same problem and answer here [How to attach to IIS process (w3wp.exe) on Windows 10/IIS 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072195/how-to-attach-to-iis-process-w3wp-exe-on-windows-10-iis-10) . The process slept, thats why it did not display in the list

Comment: Are you sure you have invoked a client to make a request to IIS?

Comment: @Ross Bush what do you mean? If you ask me "Have I checked hosted service's workability?", the answer is "Yes"

Comment: I have 2 console apps, which use this service. One of them works correct but enother one brings an error on service side.

Comment: @Vitaly -  Workability, yes. w3wp.exe can go to sleep if there is no work to do. I was just asking if you are sure you are invoking it one way or another prior to attaching the debugger.

Comment: Post what you found as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Lex Li - Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some period of time, if no one uses worker process, it stops (disappears). To start it again just select your app in IIS Manager -- right click -- Manage Website -- Browse